# How to center-align jQuery UI tabs - with screenshot

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Does anybody please know how to center-align the tabs in [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)?

(They are left aligned by default and I can't find the aligning option in the doc)

Here is [a page](http://preferans.de/user.php?id=DE10992) where I use it to groups some charts and the current code is simply:

```
$('#chart_tabs').tabs();
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** The CSS code:

```css
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
        text-align: center;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
        float: none !important;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

suggested by Didier (thanks) has center-aligned the tabs, but also put some strange gap underneath the tab-"buttons":

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This snipped help me out back in the days..

```
.centered .ui-tabs-nav {
    height: 2.35em;
    text-align: center;
}
.centered .ui-tabs-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0em;
}
```

maybe this works for you too

Comment: This has worked for me, thank you! After I've specified `<div id="chart_tabs" class="centered">....</div>`

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is to apply `text-align: center` on the container (the UL element) and unfloat the LI:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
    float: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this has added a strange gap (please see the updated question above) on all browsers I've tried... any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and avoided the gap (underneath the tabs) you mentioned:

```
.ui-tabs-nav {
  float: none; text-align: center;  
}

.ui-tabs-nav li {
  display: inline-block; float: none;  
}

.ui-tabs-nav li a {
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
  text-align: center;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
  float: none !important;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
  margin-bottom: -8px;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
  margin: 1px .2em -7px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another nice approach in modern days:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```